# BASH unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Tags: bash

I have written bash code to read values from jvmmon but I am ending up with errors while trying to evaluate values from variables

code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
str=$1
val=$2
jpid=`pgrep java`
echo $jpid
min_heap=`/usr/local/opt/bin/jvmmon -pid `$jpid` -c "print vm information" | grep -Eo '\-`$str`[^ ]+'`
```

Output:

```
./check_jvm_param: command substitution: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./check_jvm_param: command substitution: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
./check_jvm_param: command substitution: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./check_jvm_param: command substitution: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: why are you escaping `$jpid`? Paste your code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ for a good preview of the errors you have.

Comment: Have you read the error?

Comment: Ah, the wrong quotes. No need to put quotes around `$jpid`, but `$str` is a bit more tricky. Hint: use the kind of quotes that do not disable shell expansion inside the quotes.

Comment: @fedorqui and 123 yes thank you. Thank you for providing shellcheck url. I found what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to nest command substitutions using backticks. You should always use the `$(`,`)` operator for command substitution and quote your variables with double quotes, `"`.  Running your script through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) should always be a first step.